# How to increment value in counter table

Tags: postgresql

In my table I have the following scheme:

```
id - integer | date - text | name - text | count - integer
```

I want just to count some actions.

I want put 1 when `date = '30-04-2019'` not exist yet.
I want put +1 when is row already exist.

My idea is:

```
UPDATE "call" SET count = (1 + (SELECT count 
                                FROM "call" 
                                WHERE date = '30-04-2019')) 
WHERE date = '30-04-2019'
```

But it is not working when row doesn't exist.

It is possible without some extra triggers, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [writeable CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to achieve this. Additionally the UPDATE statement can be simplified to a simple `set count = count + 1` there is no need for a sub-select.

```
with updated as (
  update "call" 
     set count = count + 1
  where date = '30-04-2019'
  returning id
)
insert into "call" (date, count)
select '30-04-2019', 1
where not exists (select *
                  form updated);
```

If the update did not find a row, the `where not exists` condition will be true and the `insert` will be executed.

Note that the above is **not** safe for concurrent execution from multiple transactions. If you want to make this safe, create a `unique` index on the `date` column. Then use an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` instead:

```
insert into "call" (date, count)
values ('30-04-2019', 1)
on conflict (date) 
do update 
   set count = "call".count + 1;
```

Again: the above requires a unique index (or constraint) on the `date` column.

---

Unrelated to the immediate problem, but: storing dates in a `text` column is a **really**, really bad idea. You should change your table definition and change the data type for the `"date"` column to `date`.

Comment: @biwaheyujo: as I wrote (twice): in order to use the second solution you **have** to create a unique index on the `date` column

Comment: So I miss this information after your updates. Sorry. So, your code is working .